# Prestashop 1.6, create new block cms in the footer

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to create a new block cms in the footer containing links: new products, best products, promotions

How to edit my account block/footer?

Comment: Price drop, new products and best sales are enabled by default. Most of all you need to check `blockcms.tpl.`

Answer (score 0):

You should find `.tpl` file like `blockms.tpl`:

> Path: themes/name_of_your_theme/modules/blockcms/blockcms.tpl

[That's the source in default theme.](https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockcms/blob/master/blockcms.tpl)

Imagine that you want to add one extra link after "Our stores"...

You should find:

```
{if $display_stores_footer}
    <li class="item">
        <a href="{$link->getPageLink('stores')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Our stores' mod='blockcms'}">
            {l s='Our stores' mod='blockcms'}
        </a>
    </li>
{/if}
```

and add in next line something like:

```
{if $display_stores_footer}
    <li class="item">
        <a href="http://domain.com/lorem_ipsum" title="{l s='Lorem Ipsum' mod='blockcms'}">
            {l s='Lorem Ipsum' mod='blockcms'}
        </a>
    </li>
{/if}
```

New products, best sales and promotions are enabled by default (via CMS block module):
[image]